# OpenMP segfault when accessing array

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to make a renderer that uses multiprocessing to go faster.
I have a screenbuffer, which is an array of type color.
Color is a struct which has an r,g,b value.

```c
// gcc -fopenmp -o
// ./go
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

struct color{
  int r,g,b;
} typedef color;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int thread_id, nloops;

  color buffer[1920][1080]; // 1920 x 1080 pixels

  #pragma omp parallel private(thread_id, nloops)
  {
    nloops = 0;

    #pragma omp for
    for (int x=0; x<1920; x++){
      for (int y=0; y<1080; y++){
        nloops++;
        color *newcolor = malloc(sizeof(newcolor));
        newcolor -> r = 255;
        newcolor -> g = 255;
        newcolor -> b = 255;
        buffer[x][y] = *newcolor;
//free(color)
      }
    }

    thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

    printf("Thread %d performed %d iterations of the loop.\n",
    thread_id, nloops );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

So my question is, how do I grant access to the child processes to edit the memory used by the main process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the below statement:

```
color *newcolor = malloc(sizeof(newcolor));
```

which should be:

```
color *newcolor = malloc(sizeof(color));
```

`newcolor` is just a pointer to `color` which will have the size of a pointer (4 or 8 bytes usually). What you intended to allocate is the size of the `color` structure. This is what causes the segfault.

Note that the `typedef` should appear at the beginning of the declaration.

```
typedef struct color{
  int r,g,b;
}  color;
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved it, though after some thinking I decided to use 4 byte integers instead (think 0xRRGGBBAA). Should be faster